# TclOO class inside namespace: calling namespace procs give errors

Tags: tcl

I'm experimenting a little with TclOO from Tcl8.6 and Rivet, but I'm in trouble, because I'm not able to do what I want.

The problem is simply reproduceable with the following code inside a `.rvt` file:

```
<?

proc dumbproc {} {
    puts "this is dumbproc ([namespace current])"
}

oo::class create foo {
    method bar {} {
        puts "this is bar ([namespace current])"
        dumbproc
    }
}

set obj [foo new]

dumbproc

$obj bar
```

If I simply look at the code, it seems it should work as expected, but it really doesn't because a subtle behavior of the Rivet package and the specific configuration choosen.

In this example, I'm using a `.rvt` file whose code is executed inside the `::request` namespace, so the fully qualified name of the `dumbproc` procedure is `::request::dumbproc`. When the name resolution algorithm is called inside the `bar` method, it searches for `dumbproc` inside `::oo::Obj12`, then in `::oo`, and finally in `::`, without finding it and giving the following error.

```
this is dumbproc (::request) this is bar (::oo::Obj16)

invalid command name "dumbproc"
    while executing
"dumbproc"
    (class "::request::foo" method "bar" line 3)
    invoked from within
"$obj bar"
    (in namespace eval "::request" script line 21)
    invoked from within
"namespace eval request {
puts -nonewline ""


    proc dumbproc {} {
        puts "this is dumbproc ([namespace current])"
    }

    oo::class create..."
```

So, Tcl is *right* in doing what it does, a *feature*, then. But the behavior is *unpredictable* because when you write some class code, you must know the context it will be used in.

Indeed, I get the same error if I drop the starting `<?` Rivet magic, put the code inside a `test.tcl` file and use it in an interactive session:

```
$ tclsh
% namespace eval ::myns {source test.tcl}
this is dumbproc (::myns)
this is bar (::oo::Obj12)
invalid command name "dumbproc"
```

I tried to solve the issue by prepending the current namespace to the class creation code

```
::oo::class create [namespace current]::foo { ... }
```

then, I also tried to create the `obj` object inside the namespace

```
::oo::class create [namespace current]::foo { ... }
namespace eval [namespace current] {set obj [[namespace current]::foo new]}
```

then, I switched to the `create` method of the class for giving the object a qualified name which includes the namespace

```
foo create [namespace current]::obj
obj bar
```

but everything was unsuccessful. Every trial shows that, no matter how I do it, a method inside a TclOO class is always executed inside its object unique namespace. Am I wrong?

Is there a way to get what I want? Is TclOO not intended to work that way, and in this case why? What really surprise me is this context-dependend behavior, which I'm not sure it's the right thing, but maybe I'm completely wrong and there are sound cases for it, which I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interior of each TclOO object is in reality its *own* namespace. You can use `self namespace` or `namespace current` inside your methods to get the name of the namespace, or `info object namespace $theobj` to get the namespace from anywhere. The only command placed by default in the namespace is `my` (for calling private methods), and some commands in other namespaces are made available through the standard Tcl `namespace path` mechanism (this is how you get `self` and `next` available).

The simplest way to fix this would probably be to add this to the `foo` class's constructor:

```
namespace path [list {*}[namespace path] ::request]
```

In your specific case, you'd have to actually add a constructor...

```
constructor {} {
    namespace path [list {*}[namespace path] ::request]
    # If you had a non-trivial constructor in a superclass, you'd need to call
    # [next] too.
}
```

Longer term, it may be reasonable to ask for a mechanism for adding to the list of namespaces that are used to make the default for objects of a class. If you want that, do submit a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=10894&atid=360894)…

---

[EDIT]: If you're just after adding the parent namespace to the current object's command resolution path, you can do that by adding a bit more magic:

```
oo::class create foo {
    self {
        method create args {
            set ns [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]
            next {*}[linsert $args 1 $ns]
        }
        method new args {
            set ns [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]
            next {*}[linsert $args 0 $ns]
        }
    }
    constructor {creatorNS args} {
        namespace path [list {*}[namespace path] $creatorNS]
    }
    method bar {} {
        puts "this is bar ([namespace current])"
        dumbproc
    }
}
```

That will then automatically put the current namespace at creation on the path of the instance. If you're doing this in many classes, you probably want to create a metaclass with the majority of machinery in it, but the above technique (a `self` *declaration* of some methods on the `foo` class object itself) works fine for simple cases.

Comment: The above is a consequence of the fact that classes are ordinary objects (that know about being classes) and `new` and `create` are ordinary methods (but with implementations not in Tcl but rather — usually — in C, just like `puts` is a command implemented in C).

Comment: I have to try the metaclass approach, let's see what happens. About the feature request, I'm not sure about what to ask, because I really don't know what I need. Some more experimenting is a must. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco Generally speaking, it ends up on my TODO list anyway and I'm pretty good at turning something half-formed into a full plan. ;-)